# AppendValue in golang bigtable cli is not working as expected

Tags: go, google-cloud-bigtable

```
func writeUpdatedProfile(ctx context.Context, event *pb.Event) error {
    profile := bigtable.NewReadModifyWrite()
    profile.AppendValue("latest", "col_name", []byte(strconv.FormatInt(time.Now().UTC().Unix(),10)+":abcd|"))
    _, err := table.ApplyReadModifyWrite(ctx, event.column.key, profile)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```

This function does not update the cell and exit without an error. can anyone HELP!

let for eg. say i append "timestamp,abcd|" 3 times i am only able to see "first timestamp,abcd|" instead of "timestamp,abcd|timestamp,abcd|timestamp,abcd".

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: there is no error,but when i read the cell I can only read the first entry. let for eg. i append "4,abcd|"  3 times i am only able to see "4,abcd|" instead of "4,abcd|4,abcd|4,abcd".

Comment: Can you show how you are doing your test? Also it may be more helpful for debugging if you try appending a pattern that changes so you can see if you are reading the first or last entry.

Comment: the actual code as you can see uses timestamps. so the number 4 is just a place holder. I use row, err := table.ReadRow(ctx, event.column.key) to read from Bigtable. so i am pretty sure the reading part is not at fault.